# Overriding method provided by trait in grails unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spring-security, grails3

I have a controller with actions using the isLoggedIn() function provided by the Grails Spring Security Core plugin. I want to be able to unit test these actions, and I therefore need a way to mock the isLoggedIn() function so that it always returns false. This method is provided by a trait, which I believe is the source of my issue.

I have already tried to add a new function to the metaclass:

```
UserController.metaClass.isLoggedIn = { -> false}
```

This does not seem to be working, however; the original method is still being called.

Any suggestions as to how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the getter as:

```
UserController.metaClass.getIsLoggedIn = { -> false }
```

As an example, the following code:

```
class UserController { 
  def isLoggedIn = "original"
}


UserController.metaClass.getIsLoggedIn = { -> "get" }
UserController.metaClass.isLoggedIn    = { -> "direct" }


def u = new UserController()
println u.isLoggedIn
```

prints:

```
get
```

Comment: This solution worked after using `loggedIn` instead of `isLoggedIn()`, and overriding `getLoggedIn()`.